# Perl Algorithm:Permute and List::AllUtils (uniq)

Tags: perl

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Algorithm::Permute;
use List::AllUtils qw/uniq/;

find_perms(1151);

sub find_perms { 
  my ($value) = @_;
  my @others;
  my @digits = split(//, $value);

  my $perm = Algorithm::Permute->new( \@digits );

  while (my @next = $perm->next()) { 
    my $number = join('', @next);
    push @others, $number;
  }
  @others = sort uniq @others;

  # this one works correctly
  # @others = sort ( uniq( @others ));

  say "FOUND @others";
}

Output:
FOUND 1115 1115 1115 1115 1115 1115 1151 1151 1151 1151 1151 1151 1511 1511 1511 1511 1511 1511 5111 5111 5111 5111 5111 5111
```

Hi,

After discovering out that [Algorithm::Permute](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Algorithm%3a%3aPermute) is producing duplicates, most likely due to the amount of '1's in "1151" i decided to use `uniq`. However using `sort uniq` without the parenthesis doesn't produce expected results. But `sort(uniq(@x))` does.  What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`perldoc -f sort`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perfunc#sort) lists three syntaxes for the `sort` function:

```
sort SUBNAME LIST
sort BLOCK LIST
sort LIST
```

`sort uniq @others` matches the `sort SUBNAME LIST` syntax of sort. It expects `uniq` to be a function that compares the global variables `$a` and `$b`, and returns `<0`, `0`, or `>0` to indicate the relative ordering of `$a` and `$b`.

It looks like you were expecting and wanting the `sort LIST` syntax, which is what you get when you say one of

```
sort(uniq(@others))
sort(uniq @others)
```

Answer (score 5):

[Algorithm::Loops](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm%3a%3aLoops)'s `NextPermute` doesn't produce duplicates, so there's no need to spend memory and CPU getting rid of them.

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NextPermute );

sub find_perms { 
   my @rv;
   my @digits = sort split //, $_[0];
   do {
      push @rv, join '', @digits;
   } while NextPermute(@digits);
   return @rv;
}

say for find_perms(1151);
```

```
1115
1151
1511
5111
```

Answer (score 4):

While [@mob answered the question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11235399/100754), I would like to point out I am not sure if you want to go the `sort uniq` way. You are still storing elements you don't really want to store. In such cases, it is best to use a hash.

Also, please, [when a piece of data is meant to be a string, use a string](http://blog.nu42.com/2012/06/identifier-strings-consisting-solely-of.html). The output from `find_perms(0345)` may surprise you, but `find_perms('0345')` won't.

Finally `Algorithm::Permute::permute` is very fast.

With those considerations in mind, I would re-write your code as:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Algorithm::Permute qw( permute );

my $uniq_perms = find_perms('115122345');

sub find_perms {
  my ($value) = @_;

  my @digits = split //, $value;
  my %uniq;

  permute { $uniq{join('', @digits)} = undef } @digits;

  return [ keys %uniq ];
}
```

Comment: If I could accept two answers I would!! I'll probably go this way. thanks.